# Minimum quantity of heavy whipping cream to get whipped cream from dispenser

Tags: whipped-cream, whipping-siphon

I tried to make whipped cream with a 500mL dispenser by following the instructions (chill the dispenser for 3 hours, shake at most 7 times), but since I didn't want as much as commonly directed (2 cups), I only used 6 tbsp. However, that led to the cream coming out runny/liquid (Horizon Organic Heavy Whipping Cream, if it matters).

What is the minimum quantity of heavy whipping cream you need to put in dispenser in order to get actual whipped cream out?

Comment: I don't know the answer to this, but for such a small quantity, wouldn't it be easier to whip it by hand...?

Comment: @rumtscho: This isn't a duplicate, as I don't have access to a smaller dispenser.

Comment: @DanDascalescu it both explains the reason for the runny result and gives an answer relative to the volume of the dispenser. Do you believe it will be different for the larger dispenser?